# unable to retrieve any candidates with kb.get_candidates

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I created a csv file like this:

```
"CAMERA", "Camera", "kamera", "cam", "Kamera"
"PICTURE", "Picture", "bild", "photograph"
```

and used it somewhat like this:

```
nlp = de_core_news_sm.load()
text = "Cam is not good"
doc = nlp(text)

name_dict, desc_dict = load_entities()

kb = KnowledgeBase(vocab=nlp.vocab, entity_vector_length=96)

for qid, desc in desc_dict.items():
    desc_doc = nlp(desc)
    desc_enc = desc_doc.vector
    kb.add_entity(entity=qid, entity_vector=desc_enc, freq=342)  # 342 is an arbitrary value here

for qid, name in name_dict.items():
        kb.add_alias(alias=name, entities=[qid], probabilities=[1])  # 100% prior probability P(entity|alias)
```

Printing values like this:

```
print(f"Entities in the KB: {kb.get_entity_strings()}")
print(f"Aliases in the KB: {kb.get_alias_strings()}")
```

gives me:

```
Entities in the KB: ['PICTURE', 'CAMERA']
Aliases in the KB: [' "Camera"', ' "Picture"']
```

However, if I try to check for candidates, I only get an empty list:

```
candidates = kb.get_candidates("Camera")
print(candidates)
for c in candidates:
    print(" ", c.entity_, c.prior_prob, c.entity_vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Aliases in the KB: [' "Camera"', ' "Picture"']`

It looks to me as if your parsing script added the literal string  `"Camera"`, with spaces and quotes and all, to the KB, instead of just the raw string `Camera`?